# DocumentDB - Storing telemetry data

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, document-database, telemetry, nosql

so a quick update on why I created this question.

We currently are storing our telemetry data of our devices in the field within Azure SQL Server. This is working great (have a ton of experience with EF, LINQ and relationship dbs) BUT I am aware that this most likely isnt the best solution especially for storing "big" data (data is still small for now but will grow within a year).

I have chosen DocumentDB as our possible solution for storing of just our event history. The rest will stay in SQL - users, profiles, device info, sim, vehicle etc as I dont want to completely halt development as we move 100% across to docdb and rather just do whats best short term - cost + performance.

Going through this video I finally came up with a possible solution as to how to store telemetry data - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-o_VGpJP-Q0
They recommended One document per time period (example used 1 per hour). Is this the recommended approach still?

[image]

```
    [Index]
    public DateTime TimestampUtc { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReceivedTimestampUtc { get; set; }
    [Index]
    public EventType EventType { get; set; }
    public Guid ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public string RawEventMessage { get; set; }
    [Index]
    public Sender Sender { get; set; }
    [Index]
    public Channel Channel { get; set; }
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
    public double? Speed { get; set; }
    public double? Altitude { get; set; }
    public Int16? Heading { get; set; }
    public Byte? HDOP { get; set; }
    public Byte? GPSFixStatus { get; set; }
    public Byte? GPSFixType { get; set; }
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    public string HardwareVersion { get; set; }
    public string FirmwareVersion { get; set; }
    public string Relay1 { get; set; }
    public string Relay2 { get; set; }
    public string Relay3 { get; set; }
    public string Ign { get; set; }
    public string Doors { get; set; }
    public string Input1 { get; set; }
    public string Input2 { get; set; }
    public string Out1 { get; set; }
    public string Out2 { get; set; }
    public int V12 { get; set; }
    public int VBat { get; set; }
```

Comment: *Disclaimer - I'm one of the co-authors of the //build video you referenced* - There's really no "recommended" approach to storing telemetry data. What we showed for storing telemetry data was one specific modeling case based on some real-world solutions we've dealt with, specific to a document database such as DocumentDB (which may or may not work for your specific case). There are other ways to model, and even different database engine types.

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks for the reply :) Yeah was brain storming today and came across this good video and it gave me another option. Everything is working just fine in SQL just concerned for long term

Comment: Glad you liked it - thanks. :) And if it gave you some new things to think about, then I consider it a success.

Comment: Yeah the only thing worrying me is creating a document per event ~ one per device every 5 odd minutes. Will change in the future to possibly per second base :/ So lots to think about.

Comment: So I'm thinking my 2 options are 1 document per event (can be per second :/) or 1 document per time period (1 per hour). The data is fairly different - lat,long,time,#sats, HDOP etc. What is the downside of creating a document every second per device? Cost/performance? If thats the case I will make a document per device per time period (an hour or day).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's one of several possible alternatives. Which is best depends on what your data looks like. For instance, if you have events that vary in their start date/time and duration (or end date/time) or if you track all state changes of entities then something like [Richard Snodgrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_T._Snodgrass)' temporal data model is ideal. Interestingly Microsoft SQL Server 2016 recently added direct support for [temporal tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604462.aspx) but they've been in the SQL spec as TSQL2 for a while. Note, the TSQL2 spec includes both [valid-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_time) and [transaction-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_time) support but I believe that the recent MS SQL 2016 addition only supports valid time... but that's OK since that's what is most valuable. I only point it out because getting your head around how a valid-time table works is hard enough without the added complexity of adding transaction-time.

The beauty of this approach is that you don't have to decide on the needed time granularity as the data is collected, only if/when you aggregate it.

However, as you said, SQL is not ideal for such large data sets. So, I've implemented valid-time Richard Snodgrass style temporal model on top of DocumentDB in my [Lumenize](https://cdn.rawgit.com/lmaccherone/Lumenize/v1.0.3/docs/lumenize-docs/index.html#) library in particular the [TimeSeriesCalculator](https://cdn.rawgit.com/lmaccherone/Lumenize/v1.0.3/docs/lumenize-docs/index.html#!/api/Lumenize.TimeSeriesCalculator) and its other time-series functionality. Read pages 10-19 [here](http://maccherone.com/publications/Temporal%20data%20model%20Lookback%20Snapshots%20and%20Lumenize.pdf) for a backgrounder on the data model and common operations in the Lumenize time-series analysis. That deck is for an implementation I did while at Rally called the Lookback API built on MongoDB but the concepts are the same and I've now switched to DocumentDB (but Rally hasn't).

Another comment on your proposed model, you might want to consider a separate document for every reading. It's a bit confusing from the example if there is a document per minute or one per device. If it's one per device per hour, then you can be assured that you'll never go past 60 minutes, which would be OK, but in just about every other way I can think of, it looks like you have the risk of a single document growing unbounded which is a big no-no in DocumentDB (and all NoSQL data modeling). Also, as you say, even if it isn't unbounded, it would involve a lot of in-place updates. Since your system is likely to be write heavy, I would suggest that you might be better off with a single document per reading. If you have to store denormalized aggregations for speed later on, then you still have the option to do that. You may not even need it though. Let the performance of the production system inform that decision.

I suggest that you read up on time-dimensions for star-schemas. It looks a lot like what you are planning, but it's also ideal for the denormalized aggregation storage that I describe. I have not seen any writeups of star schema concepts for NoSQL but [here](http://learndatamodeling.com/blog/time-dimension/) is one from the traditional SQL world that will help you with the concepts.

As I said, there are a lot of alternatives and without knowing more about your situation, I cannot know which is best.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Will go through it more thoroughly ASAP, in the mean time I will explain the data rate, what the data looks like and how its used.

For now we safe to say 1 packet every 5-10 minutes so very little ... for now! Safe to say I should be designing for 1 every second but getting the data from the devices in 30-60 second blocks (kinda irrelevant).

I added some of my code first data model to my original post.

Comment: Most of the content will be null as only certain messages populate certain fields, I dont know if this effects things as well...

Comment: It's possible to indicate `null` by omitting the field. You have to be a bit careful on your queries because an actual null and a missing value will respond differently. Use `IS_DEFINED(...)` rather than `IS_NULL(...)`. This approach has advantages for storage but it also makes your indexes smaller and faster.

Comment: Ok great thanks, so I'm thinking my 2 options are 1 document per event (can be per second :/) or 1 document per time period (1 per hour). The data is fairly different - lat,long,time,#sats, HDOP etc. What is the downside of creating a document every second per device? Cost/performance? If thats the case I will make a document per device per time period (an hour or day).

Comment: Me again... after properly reading up on Azure temporal tables I am now excited about SQL again haha and possibly going to look at dealing with a massive table one day (index/scale god ;)). This will work really really well I believe in monitoring changes (door status, ign etc) really well! I guess what I need to answer is - is SQL really that bad for my design setup? Is it that bad having such a large table?

Comment: It's hard to say if MS SQL Server will handle the size of your data. One of the arguments for NoSQL and DocumentDB in particular is that you can abstract away partitioning concerns (now that DocumentDB released partitioned collections). That said, you could always manually partition your MS SQL Server tables. You'd lose some baked in join capability doing that but you don't have joins at all with NoSQL. The big argument against that is that it's more programming to support partitioned SQL.

Comment: Thanks so much Larry for all your help! I have decided to go ahead with 1 doc per event :) Will let you know how its going. Thanks again so much once again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think I am going for the 1 document per event (for now 1 every 5 minutes but could change to 1 per second per device). The reason being is appending to a document should surely be costly as you need to do a "replace" on that document?? (does docdb support append/partial updates now?) Surely that involves a read and then a growing replace which would be more costly and timely than just adding a new doc per event. The only concern is when we have millions/billions of documents... is this fine?